# How can I sort the column heading in MS Access for more than 30 columns

Tags: ms-access

Example:

```
Roll_Number |   Class   |   Subject     |   Marks   |   DOB
------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+------------
1           |   11      |   Chemistry   |   50      |   14-05-96
2           |   12      |   Physics     |   62      |   15-02-93
```

It should be like

```
Class   |   DOB         |   Marks   |   Roll_Number |   Subject
--------+---------------+-----------+---------------+--------------
11      |   14-05-96    |   50      |   1           |   Chemistry
12      |   15-02-93    |   62      |   2           |   Physics
```

Comment: That's not clear enough. Column headings of what kind of object?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the columns to be sorted in a particular way just list them in SELECT statement the way you want them, e.g.,

```sql
SELECT [Class], [DOB], [Marks], ... FROM [table]
```